# IE10 does not support stylesheet link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I have iframe, which loaded dynamically. Content in this iframe should be styled like page on which it's located. To do this I added link to css file to iframe head. It works OK in Firefox, but it doesn't work in IE10. Is it known issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dialogIframe').load(function(){
                $('#dialogIframe')
                        .contents().find("body")
                        .html("test iframe");
                $('#dialogIframe')
                        .contents().find("head")
                        .html('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
Test
<iframe id="dialogIframe" style="width:300px; height:300px; border: none;">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YwCRf/

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work in IE, you can find at [MSDN: innerHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html).

Comment: "Not working" is always a feature of IE :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`innerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html) of `head` is read-only in IE, the snippet below does the trick:

```
$('#dialogIframe')
    .contents().find("head")
    .append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">')
);
```

---

Just in case somebody would need to do this with pure JavaScript, here's the code:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('dialogIframe').contentWindow.document,
    sheet = doc.createElement('link');
sheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
sheet.type = 'text/css';
sheet.href = '/css/main.css';
doc.documentElement.appendChild(sheet);
```

Comment: +1, although of course I'd prefer the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) version.

Comment: @Kolink So would I, but the code in the question is jQuery. If I'd have answered with pure JS, somebody would have probably downvoted the answer.

Comment: You suck! Not enough jQuery! XD in my experience, I've gotten more +1s for posting Vanilla JS in a jQuery question. I have the gold jQuery badge even though I've written maybe two answers in jQuery.

Comment: @Kolink There you have it now. Maybe you have more authority with rep over 100K, I've sometimes got downvotes when have answered with pure JS to jQuery -tagged questions.

Comment: I only recently got 100k, but a lot of it came from that kind of answer XD

Comment: @Teemu Could you also explain, why code to load iframe content does not work in IE8 even if I don't load css? I see just empty frame. When I debug it, I see that we don't enter into load function.

Comment: @ValentinaChumak I'm not sure, but it's possible, that `iframe.onload` has already triggered, when IE8 fires the `$(document).ready()`. If I can recall correctly, `$(document).ready()` is not reliable in older IEs.

Comment: @Teemu I used onload="loadiframe()" instead of jquery, and my test page works! Also thank you very match for pure JavaScript code, because adding stylesheet by jquery also doesn't work in IE8. Interesting, why...

Comment: @ValentinaChumak Which jQuery version are you using? jQuery-2.X doesn't support IE<9, you need to use jQquery-1.X in those legacy browsers. And thanks to Kolink, who "forced" me to add the vanilla JS snippet too : ).

Comment: @Teemu in our project 1.8.3 is used

Comment: @ValentinaChumak Works for me (emulated IE8 with IE10 though). Maybe you should post a new question about this, someone having a real IE8 might have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents (more browser compatible)

```
// locate iframe
var frameName = "dialogIframe"; 
var iframe    = document.frames ? document.frames[frameName] : window.frames[frameName];

// create stylesheet    
var ss  = iframe.document.createElement("link");
ss.type = "text/css";
ss.rel  = "stylesheet";
ss.href = "style.css";

// apply to iframe's head
document.all ? iframe.document.createStyleSheet(ss.href) : iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```

Comment: There was not `name` attribute in the post, so I've used `id` in my answer. Anayway, you don't need to check whether you can find `frames` collection from `document` or not, it's in `window` in any browser, optionally you can find it also from `document` in some browsers. Also `iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);` is a cross-browser method. A question: Why do we create `link` element within `iframe`'s document instead of the document where our code is placed?

Comment: iframe array can be accesed by id. You're right about "window.frames". I used createStyleSheet cause is a native IE function (maybe faster).
About the link element creation, as far as I know there is no difference.

(createStyleSheet is deprecated in IE 11) That's why I prefeer to use Jquery whenever possible.

Comment: Yep, no difference in case of `iframe`, but if it would be a pop-up window, you would get an error in IE, when trying to append an element from another document.

Comment: About the link element creation, I think you must create the node in the document you want to attach it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2291553/2706287